# How to iterate over files in directory in python with respect to size

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have a directory with thousands of files, I want to rename them with respect to their sizes, i.e the name of the biggest file is going to be 0001.txt then 0002.txt and so on. To do so iterating over whole directory  with

```
for filename in files:
    print(filename)
```

is very very costly. Is there an easy an quicker way to do so?

Comment: Is it that `print` that takes up so much time? It is, isn't it? If you do not print out all file names, your script will run much faster. (Actually we cannot tell for sure because you do not provide what other code you run.)

Comment: I do not print the names of the files in the main code, that was just an example, instead i rename the files. There is no cost in just one loop, however I was sorting them in another loop, so the answer of @Mozzie cleand up the mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over all the files. You can load all the files with respect to size, sort, then rename. Thousands of files isn't much data in the grand scheme of things.

```
import os
sorting_data = []
for filename in files:
    sorting_data.append((filename,os.path.getsize(filename)))
# Sort data by size
sorting_data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=true)
# Rename files
for i in range(0, len(sorting_data)):
    name = sorting_data[i][0]
    os.rename(name, str(i))
```

Comment: You need to sort files in reverse order to get the biggest file first.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal thanks for pointing it out, I wrote that code without testing it.

Comment: I thought so. `NameError: name 'files' is not defined` (but OP should really have provided a [mcve] that runs correctly).